# deploying a directory structure to new path

Tags: node.js, deployment, directory, package

I am using [bower](http://twitter.github.com/bower/) packaging system to fetch files to local project however breaking conventions these files are useless on their own. They need to be injected in the proper location in the MVC framework I'm using so whatever bower fetches I need to essentially do a post action and copy the directory structure / files from `components/myexample/` to `application/`

**remote bower package:**

```
controllers
   mycontroller.php
models
   mymodel.php
view
  layout
     myview.php
composer.json
```

**local project:**

```
composer.json
components
  myexample
      controllers
        mycontroller.php
      models
       mymodel.php
      view
       layout
         myview.php

application
   controllers
   models
   view
```

I was thinking of upon retrieving the directory structure and files to zip it all and then do an extract to the right directory. I need the solution to be cross platform compatible. How would you do it and better yet how else would you implement this?

Comment: At first you had a `perl` tag, then you replaced it with a `python` tag and then bstpierre replaced it with `node.js`. So... which is it? What kind of a solution to you seek?

Comment: hey sorry I reached the tag limits had to pick one, I don't mind the solution as long as it is cross platform